# Discord.js: How to make sure bot doesn't pick two of the same words from a list

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm making a guessing game in discord.js, where the bot picks 4 random words from a list, puts them in the chat, and you have to reply with the same words. Here's an abbreviated and simpler version of what I'm trying to do:

```
const profileModel = require("../models/profileSchema");
module.exports = {
    name: "guess",
    description: "guessing game",
    async execute(client, message, args, Discord, profileData) {
        let words = [
            "red",
             "orange",
             "yellow",
             "green",
             "blue",
             "purple",
             "pink",
             "black",
             "white"
         ]
         let firstWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
         let secondWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
         let thirdWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]; 
         let fourthWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

         message.reply(`Type the following words into chat: \`${firstWord}\` \`${secondWord}\` \`${thirdWord}\` \`${fourthWord}\``)
           .then((msg) => {
               setTimeout(function() {
                   msg.edit('Type the words into chat!');
               }, 5000)});  
               message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == message.author.id, { max: 1, time: 10000 }).then(collected => {
                   if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == `${firstWord} ${secondWord} ${thirdWord} ${fourthWord}`) {
                       message.reply('Correct!');
                   } else
                       message.reply('Incorrect');
               }).catch(() => {
                   message.reply('No answer after 10 seconds, time out.');
               });
           });
    }
}
```

How do I make it so that the bot doesn't pick the same word twice? For example, make it so that it can't say something like "blue blue green orange". Thanks!

Comment: After it chooses the word you could store the word in a temp variable, and check if that is equal to the next word that it chooses. If it is, then choose another word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a very simple way, you could do as following:

1. After you assign the word, cut the element off the array using the `splice()` function:

```js
index = words.indexOf(firstWord);
words.splice(index, 1);
```

2. Repeat for other words, as following:

```js
let firstWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
index = words.indexOf(firstWord);
words.splice(index, 1);
let secondWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
index = words.indexOf(secondWord);
words.splice(index, 1);
let thirdWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
index = words.indexOf(thirdWord);
words.splice(index, 1);
let fourthWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
index = words.indexOf(fourthWord);
words.splice(index, 1);
```

Finally the bot will remove the element from the `words[]` array, until the command will be recalled.

References:

- [splice() function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)